# How to add class label ul CheckboxSelectMultiple django

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

**MY FORM**

```
'warranty': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'list-inline'}),
```

**MY TEMPLATE**

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="height: 50px;  width: 900px;">
   <label class="list-inline col-xs-6" for="{{form2.warranty.name}}" style="width: 140px; padding-right: 20px;padding-left: 20px;">{{ form2.warranty.label }}</label>
   {{ form2.warranty}}
</div>
```

**Result**

```
<ul id=id_class>
  <li class="list-inline id="id_warranty_1" name="warranty">opcion 1</li>
  <li class="list-inline id="id_warranty_2" name="warranty">opcion 2</li>
  <li class="list-inline id="id_warranty_3" name="warranty">opcion 3</li>
</ul>
```

**But I need my class LIST-INLINE on the**

```
<ul class="MYCLASS" id=id_class>
  <li class="list-inline id="id_warranty_1" name="warranty">opcion 1</li>
  <li class="list-inline id="id_warranty_2" name="warranty">opcion 2</li>
  <li class="list-inline id="id_warranty_3" name="warranty">opcion 3</li>
</ul>
```

PROBLEM ACTUAL

[image: Current unwanted result]

desired result

[image: desired result]